# ffmpeg, 'protocol not found' error

Tags: c, ffmpeg

i'm using next code:

```
const char *sFileOutput;
AVOutputFormat *ofmt;
AVFormatContext *ofcx;

        int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
        {
            av_log_set_level( AV_LOG_DEBUG );
            av_register_all();
            avcodec_register_all();
            avformat_network_init();

            char s1[40]={0};
            const time_t timer = time(NULL);
            u = localtime(&timer);
            strftime(s1, 40, "%d.%m.%Y-%H:%M:%S.avi", u);
            sFileOutput=&s1;

            //char *sFileOutput = "01.01.2017-23.23.23.avi";

            ofmt = av_guess_format( NULL, sFileOutput, NULL );
            ofcx = avformat_alloc_context();
            ofcx->oformat = ofmt;
            int ret2=avio_open( &ofcx->pb, sFileOutput, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
            if(ret2<0){
                fprintf(stderr, "\nError occurred when opening output file: %s\n",av_err2str(ret2));
            }
        }
```

When i run it, i have error in console:

```
Error occurred when opening output file: Protocol not found
```

but if i uncomment string

```
char *sFileOutput = "01.01.2017-23.23.23.avi";
```

evirything is ok, progam is working without errors. please tell me what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your answer, it helps me too. 
But real problem was that generated name contained ':'. i changed string to

```
strftime(s1, 40, "%d.%m.%Y-%H.%M.%S.avi", u);
```

and it works well.

Comment: You can use `:` if you escape it.

Comment: @aergistal is correct about this one you can't have `:` inside the file name. I just renamed the file I wanted to change and wholla it started working.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
sFileOutput=&s1
```

`&s1` creates a pointer of type `char (*)[40]` and not a pointer to the first element of the array like you expect. You are passing around a pointer to the entire array which gets converted to an incompatible type. Check the compilation warnings/errors.

The solution is to use either the implicit conversion:

```
sFileOutput=s1
```

or:

```
sFileOutput=&s1[0]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it helps me too. But real problem was that generated name contained ':'. i changed string to